# Configuring Desire2Learn LIS Outcomes

Tags: desire2learn, valence

How can I configure an **External Learning Tool** to send an `lis_outcome_service_url` to my LTI provider if they support that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the LMS provide support for `lis_outcome_service_url` in LTI launches requires that your back-end service be of a vintage that supports LTI 1.1. Support for LTI 1.1 arrived with D2L Learning Suite v10.1.0. If your LMS is older than that, it will not support the outcome service (so you won't be able to send the property in launches); if your LMS is that vintage or newer, then it should automatically put the `lis_outcome_service_url` property in launches without need for extra configuration: if a grade item isn't already associated with the external learning tool, then the Tool Provider's use of the outcome service will automatically create a grade item; otherwise, you can associate an existing grade item with the external learning tool and the outcome service will use that association.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I see now that every LTI launch post sends a `lis_outcome_service_url`. I was assuming that the `lis_outcome_service_url` parameter was only sent for LTI tools that were marked as 'Gradeable' in the LMS. This means that the LTI Producer will have to prompt the instructor whether or not they intend   the content to be gradeable, and send a grade back to the LMS Consumer.